# graphapi remote lock status query

Tags: mobile, microsoft-graph-api, mdm

I have been testing the remote locking ability for intune using CURL and I am getting the managed device to lock but its response is slow, sometimes taking many seconds to respond. I understand that there may be factors impacting the speed of the response but what I would like to know:

- Is there any mechanism in place to get the status/results of a remote lock request ?  I have tried the action documented here :

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

  But this always returns an empty value for deviceActionResults.
- I found documentation for remote lock action status :

  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/intune-devices-remotelockactionresult?view=graph-rest-beta

  but I would like to know more information about the api to access this information (assuming it is not just documenting the deviceActionResults portion of the get device information request

Thanks in advance for any leads

Answer (score 0):

If you call the device again using the API, there are deviceActionResults in the resulting JSON:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/('$($ManagedDevice.id)')"
$Device = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $authToken -Method Get
$Device.deviceActionResults.PIN
```

From this you can get the PIN, this worked for me.